# While loop not working correctly in C calendar program?

Tags: c, while-loop

The objective of my code is to be able to have the user input an integer value (`delta`), and `delta` is the amount of days in which the code will display the date from the date now. So for example today's date is `September 24, 2015`, if the user entered `10` as `delta`, the computer would output the new date `October 4,2015`. I know that one can use the `time.h` standard library, but I am trying to do this part without using those functions, I want to really get the fundamentals down. I am having trouble with the while loop though, I can change the number of days, but changing the month/year is not working for me. I have typed this part of my current code below. I am new to C, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int domToday();
int monthToday();
int yeartoday();
int calcDays();

void printDate(int year, int month, int dom);

struct tm *now;
time_t timer;

int numberOfDays;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int delta = 0;

if (argc!=2) {
    printf("Expect a single argument... number of days from today.\n");
    printf("Assuming today's date (delta=0)\n");
    printf("Enter the number of days\n"); // change later
    scanf("%i", &delta);
} else delta=atoi(argv[1]);

int year=yearToday();
int month=monthToday();
int dom=domToday();


while(delta>0) {

    if (month == 12 && dom>numberOfDays) {
        ++year;
        month = 1;
        dom = 0;
        ++dom;
        --delta;
    }
    else if(dom>numberOfDays) {
        ++month;
        --delta;
        dom = 0;
        ++dom;
    }
    else {
        ++dom;
        --delta;
    }
}


printDate(year,month,dom);

}

int calcDays(month,year){
int numberOfDays;  
    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)  
        numberOfDays = 30;  
    else if (month == 2)  {
        bool isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);  
    if (isLeapYear)  
         numberOfDays = 29;  
    else  
            numberOfDays = 28;  
    }  
    else  
        numberOfDays = 31; 
    }



int domToday() {
    timer=time(NULL);
    now = localtime(&timer);
    return now->tm_mday;
}

int monthToday() {
    timer=time(NULL);
    now = localtime(&timer);
    return now->tm_mon+1;
}

int yearToday() {
    timer=time(NULL);
    now = localtime(&timer);
    return now->tm_year+1900;
}

void printDate(int year, int month, int dom) {
    /* The following assertions make sure that the arguments are valid numbers */
    assert(year>=0);
    assert(month>0);
    assert(month<=12);
    assert(dom>0);
    assert(dom<=31);
    char* monthNames[12]={"January","February","March","April","May",
            "June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
    printf("New date is: %s %2d, %d\n",monthNames[month-1],dom,year);
}
```

Comment: Where are the `while` loop opening and closing curly braces `{...}`?

Comment: Why are you incrementing `dom` in the `else if` block?

Comment: forgot to add them, but i have them in the actual code and it still doesn't work

Comment: @HappyCoder In this particular case, they are not needed (but should be there for clarity) since the rest are `else` blocks.

Comment: i incremented dom because when the dom is greater then the number of days in the month, the program is supposed to change to the next month, reset the day to 1, and keep adding the amount of delta days

Comment: @OwenSantangelo If you are resetting to 1, and then incrementing it, then it becomes `2`. So, the next date after `31 Jan` would become `2 Feb`.

Comment: i used an assert statement below to make sure the dom never exceeded 31 no matter what, so say i put in 10 to try and make the date a new month, i just get the assert error where dom cant be greater then 31

Comment: Though not the answer to your question, but if you use `{...}` for `while`, you can write common statements only once, instead of writing them for each branch!

Comment: @Anachor so should i set dom = to 0 then?

Answer (score -2):

As HappyCoder said, there are missing brackets on the while

Your code:

```
while(delta > 0)

    if (month == 12 && dom > numberOfDays) {
        ++year;
        month = 1;
        dom = 1;
        ++dom;
        --delta;
    }

    else if(dom > numberOfDays) {
        ++month;
        --delta;
        dom = 1;
        ++dom;
    }

    else {
        ++dom;
        --delta;
    }
```

What you should have:

```
while(delta > 0) {

    if (month == 12 && dom > numberOfDays) {
        ++year;
        month = 1;
        dom = 1;
        ++dom;
        --delta;
    }

    else if(dom > numberOfDays) {
        ++month;
        --delta;
        dom = 1;
        ++dom;
    }

    else {
        ++dom;
        --delta;
    }
}
```

Comment: Braces aren't needed here (though should be helpful for clarity)

Comment: @HappyCoder the braces don't fix my error though, they do help with the clarity though